# Multiplicative inverse of $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ and $\mathbb{Z}_7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm working on some exercises. I've got this question:

"Find the multiplicative inverse of $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ and $\mathbb{Z}_7.$

My idea is that I should solve an equation, 
$ab=1$ and I'm not sure if I did it correctly. Here is my work.

For the first, $\mathbb{Z}_5$

I've got
$3\cdot b=1\Leftrightarrow b=\frac{1}{3}=3^{-1}$, hence
$3\cdot 3^{-1}=1 \pmod 5$ which gives me $1$. So if I use $3^{-1} \pmod 5 $ I will get $2$. So,

The inverse of $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is $2$?

Hope it's clear, thank you.

Comment: Is it $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$ the field with $5$ elements, or $\Bbb Z_5$ the $5$-adic integers?

Comment: I think it's a field since I've never heard about 5-adic integers.

Answer (score 1):

The multiplicative inverse of $3$ in $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$ is $2$, since $3 \times_5 2 = 2 \times_5 3 = 1$.

The multiplicative inverse of $3$ in $\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z$ is $5$, since $3 \times_7 5 = 5 \times_7 3 = 1$.

Comment: I've got the same as you, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to solve $3x \equiv 1 \bmod 5$ and $3x \equiv 1 \bmod 7$.
For fun, you can even solve these equations simultaneously, that is, $3x \equiv 1 \bmod 35$. This is easy because the solution $x=12$ jumps out, since $3 \cdot 12 = 36 = 35 +1$. Therefore,

$x =12 \equiv 2 \bmod 5$ solves $3x \equiv 1 \bmod 5$

$x =12 \equiv 5 \bmod 7$ solves $3x \equiv 1 \bmod 7$

Comment: I will Try, Thanks!